# Understanding the constraint of tension with a rigid body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

I want to know why doesn't $T_1 = T_2$? I think its probably because of the Pulley but still aren't the Tensions Equal but opposite in direction.

Comment: At this point, it's totally unclear as what you are asking. Why do you consider $T_1= T_2\;?$

Comment: They're the same string, so shouldn't their forces balance

Comment: The absolute values of both tensions are the same, but the directions of the forces they exert on the masses are not. Maybe the book tries to point that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pulley has a non-zero moment of inertia, and, since the blocks are accelerating, the angular acceleration of the pulley is non-zero.  So the string must apply a net torque on the pulley to bring about its angular acceleration. That means that the tension $T_1$ must be greater than the tension $T_2$.